# Angular JS - Model not consistant in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a custom directive in my angular code

```
app.directive('ngMatch', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: true,
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, control) {
            var checker = function () {

                //get the value of the first password
                var e1 = scope.$eval(attrs.ngModel);
                //get the value of the other password  
                var e2 = scope.$eval(attrs.ngMatch);
                console.log(e1 + ' == ' + e2);
                return e1 == e2;

            };
            scope.$watch(checker, function (n) {

                //set the form control to valid if both 
                //passwords are the same, else invalid
                control.$setValidity("match", n);
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

however when I run this I'm getting the following results logged

```
t == undefined 
undefined == undefined
tes == undefined
undefined == undefined
```

can anybody shed any light on this for me?

Comment: Rather than use `scope.$eval` you may want to do bindings through the isolate scope like `scope: {"ng-match": "@"}` or perhaps use `attrs["ng-match"]` but I'm not positive

Comment: What does it look like where you are using it? A fiddle or plnkr would be real useful here.

Comment: @dnc253 It seems more useful than expected - it turns out that I've been using 1.3.0-beta.13 - switching 1.2.18 causes the code to work as expected. It's moments like these that leave you wondering about your own sanity. Cheers